# HTML/CSS - Background Image Not Working

Tags: html, css

I need a background image on my website. I've set it on my .CSS file, which is in a sub-folder. The background image only works if I put the .CSS file on the main website's folder.

I have those folders:
_src  (html files source)
_src/_img  (where all the images are stored)
_src/_css  (where I've put the style.css)

**In the head section of my HTML file I use the href equals to _src/_css/style.css**

**In the body section on my .CSS file I set the background-image the url _src/_img/red_lines_bg_texture.jpg.

If I move the .CSS file to the Website's root the background image works.
Strangely enough, everything else works on the .CSS file, except - again - the background image.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: `../_img/image.jpg` try this relative path

Answer (score 0):

URLs in CSS are always relative to the .css file unless otherwise specified, for instance, with a beginning slash as in "/imgdir/img.jpg"

Your background image can be set with an absolute url like this

```
background-image: url('/_src/_img/red_lines_bg_texture.jpg');
```

with a beginning slash to specify that you are giving a path relative to the root, rather than relative to the .css file.

Comment: The quotes aren't important, it's the slash at the beginning of the url

Comment: I've got the solution.
I have the following directory structure relative to the root:
\_src
\_src\_css
\_src\_img.

CSS files only acccess folders RELATIVE TO ITS OWN LOCATION, so in order to access files in _img folder we should use the relative path, like this:

background-image:url("../_img/red_lines_bg_texture.jpg");

It finally works.

Thanks to everyone who tried to help.

Answer (score -1):

I've got the solution.
I have the following directory structure relative to the root:

```
/_src
/_src/_css
/_src/_img.
```

CSS files only acccess folders RELATIVE TO ITS OWN LOCATION, so in order to access files in _img folder we should use the relative path, like this:

background-image:url("../_img/red_lines_bg_texture.jpg");

It finally works.

Thanks to everyone who tried to help.

Comment: This works, but it gives you less flexibility in reorganizing your directories.  I always go with absolute paths for images in CSS unless those images are in the same folder or a subfolder with the .css file.

Comment: You are right, but I tried to use absolute path on my CSS file but it simply did not work. Just to let you know, I'm very familiar with MS-DOS and Unix, so directory structure is not a problem to me.
I've used "/", "\" and everything possible but nothing has worked except for those two options: - Save the CSS file on the root, or use a relative path from the CSS file location to the image folder location. I'll take some time in the future, once I can't do that now, to research that deeply.